# SnackBar covers FAB

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button, android-support-design, android-snackbar

My layout is absolutely identical with [this tutorial](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling(part3)). But in this tutorial we use `app:layout_behavior="pl.michalz.hideonscrollexample.ScrollingFABBehavior"`
in Fab XML, so `SnackBar` covers the Fab. Without this code Fab does not move followed by `RecyclerView`. How to show `SnackBar` correctly?

```
Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout),
adapter.getNewsList().get(position).getTitle(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you follow is pretty unlucky. The default behavior of `FloatingActionButton` within `CoordinatorLayout` is to move up when you display `SnackBar`. Since this code overrides the `Behavior` you lose this feature because the methods never call their super class implementations. Clearly the author have not thought about this. However, you can modify the `ScrollingFABBehavior` to extend the original `Behavior` and thus support `SnackBar`:

```
public class ScrollingFABBehavior extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {
    private int toolbarHeight;

    public ScrollingFABBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super();
        this.toolbarHeight = Utils.getToolbarHeight(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton fab, View dependency) {
        return super.layoutDependsOn(parent, fab, dependency) || (dependency instanceof AppBarLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton fab, View dependency) {
        boolean returnValue = super.onDependentViewChanged(parent, fab, dependency);
        if (dependency instanceof AppBarLayout) {
            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
            int fabBottomMargin = lp.bottomMargin;
            int distanceToScroll = fab.getHeight() + fabBottomMargin;
            float ratio = (float)dependency.getY()/(float)toolbarHeight;
            fab.setTranslationY(-distanceToScroll * ratio);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

*This is actually the class from the example's [github repository](https://github.com/mzgreen/HideOnScrollExample), I have found it just after I coded the same myself and wanted to test it. They only forgot to update the blog post :-/*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
...
View view = inflater.inlfate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, false);
...
Snackbar.make(view.findViewById(R.id.fab),
        adapter.getNewsList().get(position).getTitle(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
...
return view;
```

I assume that you call above code in `Fragment`, so I added `view` variable to call the `findViewById()` method.